# Book of applications of the theory of singularities to the geometry of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, singularity-theory

I've been searching the web for the book :

***BANCHOFF, T., GAFFNEY, T. and MCCRORY, C. Cusps of Gauss mappings (Research Notes in Mathematics 55, Pitman, 1981)***

on the web but I have not found references, if anyone has information that you can provide me, I am very grateful.

Comment: @Masacroso The first is a review of the book. The second is an article by McCrory and me. I assumed the OP wanted (free) access to the book, which I doubt is available.

Comment: @Masacroso the first link is a summary, which I have already found before and the second is another article

Comment: @Julian you are right. I found an online version [here](https://www.emis.de/monographs/CGM/).